Aristotle's problem of the continuum and mereological nihilism
Aristotle explains that "it is impossible for something continuous to be made of indivisibles, such as, for example, a line being composed of points, if we take for granted that the line is a continuum and the point is indivisible” (cf. Physics, Book VI, 23la).
Put in a more technical manner: the thesis that asserts that extension is composed of inextensive (indivisible) parts in such a way that the parts are positioned next to one another without intervals between them is absurd.
If mereological nihilism is upheld, which posits that everything is simple (there is never any composition), how does it respond to this problem?

Aristotle's critique assumes a metaphysical commitment to the reality of both the continuum and the indivisible point. Mereological nihilists might argue that continuity is not a fundamental ontological feature of the world but rather a feature of how humans perceive and conceptualize it. For example, a line is not "real" in the sense of being an entity made of discrete parts or indivisibles; instead, it is a useful artifact that emerges from our way of describing the spatial relationships between fundamental simples...

Why would mereological nihilists have to respond to a problem that by their philosophy doesn't exist?

Often mereological nihilism restricts itself to material objects, so a point and a line are beyond the scope of the claim

Leibniz, who was a mereological nihilist according to Harmer, writes in a 1706 letter to de Volder:"Of course, the continuum involves indeterminate parts, but, nevertheless, nothing is indefinite in actual things. Indeed, any division that can be made in actual things has been made... There are actually parts in a real whole, but not in an ideal whole." "An infinite composed from parts is neither one nor a whole, and it is not conceived as a quantity except through a fiction of the mind."

@Conifold Curiously, I came across that work while asking the question. It’s very interesting, and it had never occurred to me to read Leibniz in that light.

@DavidGudeman I suppose it’s because it begs the question: we are seeing a line, and I don’t understand the leap between "seeing" a line and explaining it as something non-existent.

@DoubleKnot I do agree with your response. But how does our mind produce a composition that never occurs in reality? The only answer I can think of is that it is an illusion, just like an optical illusion.

@Ian per modern neuroscience, even raw vision sense occurs in cortex perceived in mind has already been theory-laden and thus illusory, representation all the way down...

@DoubleKnot I don’t believe that the phenomenological experience can be reduced or eliminated to mere neural processes. This doesn’t mean that I think phenomenological intentional consciousness is ineliminable; however, I don’t believe it can be naturalized.

@Ian not conflict here since I'm claiming in the natural attitude, and indeed if purely eliminative via NCC it's not easy to attain eidetic especially in the higher hierarchy of compositions, if even possible at all. Though continuum are illusions but they persist for pragmatic uses as children can easily draw them instead of much truer non-illusory mereological simples. And bear in mind again mereology alone without being bracketed itself cannot even express order...

@DoubleKnot What do you mean by "mereology alone without being bracketed itself cannot even express order"?

One defense is simply object eliminativism. This is the view that composite objects do not exist. Your cat does not exist. Instead, it is just a conglomerate of molecules that travel together. Though, molecules don't exist either, so that leaves you with just a bunch of fermions and bosons.
Under this view, either the line is simple and is not composed of points, or the points are simple and the line does  not exist.
